# does java support compile time polymorphism or not?

Tags: java, oop, polymorphism

according to my understanding, only virtual functions supports runtime polymorphism according to OOPS concepts and in java all functions except marked private, final, and static are virtual by default.

so does it mean that, java does not support compile time polymorphism?

and if it does, then can we assume that its a violation of OOPs  principles.

Comment: Define "compile time polymorphism".

Comment: A violation of *which* OOP principles? Where does it say an OO language must support compile time polymorphism? Why are these alleged OOP principles always referred to without a proper citation?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about a coding problem and belongs on http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Comment: OO language says  that if functions are virtual then there is  run time polymorphism and in java all functions are virtual by default. if all functions are virtual and how java supports compile time polymorphism

Comment: I guess this would be asking if there is an equivalent in java of the [Curiously recurring template pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) from c++.

Answer (score 7):

Method overloading is a compile time Polymorphism. As we can have multiple subtype implementations for a super type, the compiler determines which type to be invoked at the compile time, because all the methods are bind at compile time

for ex:

```
public class GamePlayer {

     public void doSomething(Worker worker) {
      System.out.println("I'm a worker");
     }

     public void doSomething(Teacher teacher) {
      System.out.println("I'm a Teacher");
     }

     public void doSomething(Principal principal) {
      System.out.println("I'm a Principal");
     }

     public static void main(String[] args) {

      GamePlayer example = new GamePlayer();
      Worker principal = new Principal();
      Worker teacher = new Teacher();

      example.doSomething(principal);
      example.doSomething(teacher);
     }
    }
```

You would expect the output as

```
I'm a Principal
I'm a Teacher
```

but, the actual output will be

```
I'm a worker
I'm a worker
```

Reason:: Here the type is decided at compile time. Even though the objects are instances of Principal and Teacher, the reference is of Worker type. So the compiler picks the doSomething(Worker worker) method as it accepts the same type of reference type (Worker)..

Answer (score 1):

Well Function Overloading is Compile Time Polymorphism since the compiler knows which function to call based on the arguments during compile time.

Comment: "Overloading" is an overloaded concept. They are basically two different methods. Lets not confuse people with one more oops term "compile time polymorphism"